# How to Get Clicked KML point coordination in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I want to get clicked point's coordinates. However I get "undefined" string.

The code is below

```
    kmlLayer.addListener("click", (kmlEvent) => {
        const text = kmlEvent.featureData.coordinates;
        window.alert(text);
    });
```

And my .kml file sample:

```
<Placemark>
        <name>AYRANCI MAHALLESİ</name>
        <description>DİKMEN CAD. UÇARLI SOKAK CEMAL SÜREYA PARKI 2 ADET GERİ DÖNÜŞÜM KUMBARASI</description>
        <styleUrl>#icon-165</styleUrl>
        <Point>
          <coordinates>
            32.8466184,39.9044488,0
          </coordinates>
        </Point>
</Placemark>
```

I can get the description of placemark but could not get the coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates of the clicked feature are at the [`KmlEvent`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/kml#KmlMouseEvent) level, not in the `featureData` information:

> `google.maps.KmlMouseEvent` interface
>
> The properties of a click event on a KML/KMZ or GeoRSS document.
>
> **Properties**
> `...`
> **latLng**    
> Type:  LatLng
> The position at which to anchor an infowindow on the clicked feature.
> `...`

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/kq5stob4/)

[image: screenshot of infowindow displaying the feature's coordinates]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    },
  });
  const kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: "http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20210403_Placemark.kml",
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });
  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  kmlLayer.addListener("click", (kmlEvent) => {
    const text = kmlEvent.latLng.toUrlValue(6);
    const description = kmlEvent.featureData.description;
    const name = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
    infowindow.setContent("<b>" + name + "</b><br>" + description + "<br>" + text);
    infowindow.setPosition(kmlEvent.latLng)
    infowindow.open(map);
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
  </body>

</html>
```